# Select entire row based on max value with where clause

Tags: mysql

In MySQL I'm tasked with the following accounting task:

- I have to find the entire row with the newest date in month (given month number)
- Where text = b

I took a snippet from the database to demonstrate my problem.

input:

```
date        text
----------  ----
2015-05-01   b
2015-04-30   a
2015-04-29   b
2015-04-29   a
2015-04-28   b
```

expected:

```
date        text
----------  ----
2015-04-29   b
```

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT MAX(date), text
FROM table1
WHERE MONTH(date) = 4
AND text = b
```

But it does not return the correct text. I have tried solving the problem using this link [SQL Select only rows with Max Value on a Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column) - but I can't get it to work.

What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `ORDER BY` the `date` column in descending order and then retain only the first row, which is the row with the largest (i.e. most recent) date:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE text = 'b' AND MONTH(date) = 4
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 1
```